# Автоматизация работы на сайте с seleniumrequests

Tags: python

Пытаюсь автоматизировать процесс авторизации и работы на сайте с помощью seleniumrequests.
Авторизацию на сайте прохожу отлично, если через библиотеку requests - всегда просит подтверждения, что я не робот

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox
import requests
 
driver_1x = Firefox()
 
user_1x = '00000000'
password_1x = '00000000'
driver_1x.get("https://1xstavka.ru/")
 
driver_1x.find_element_by_id('curLoginForm').click()
driver_1x.find_element_by_id('auth_id_email').send_keys(user_1x)
driver_1x.find_element_by_id('auth-form-password').send_keys(password_1x)
driver_1x.find_element_by_class_name('auth-button__text').click()
```

Пробовал проходить авторизацию через requests, но просит подтверждения, что я не робот.
После авторизации, с помощью requests получаю все данные с сайта и программа ищет определенное событие на сайте. Когда событие найдено, мне необходимо, что программа сама добавила событие в купон на сайте. Если в ручную, самому в браузере это делать, то отправляется post-запрос с данными в json-формате в таком виде:

```
json = {'CfView' : 0, 'Events' : [{
        'Coef' : test_1x[0]['1'], #значение из цикла( коэффициент на нужное событие)
        'Expired' : 0,
        'GameId' : test_1x[0]['ID'], #значение из цикла(ID события)
        'InstrumentID': 0,
        'Kind' : 1,
        'Param' : 0,
        'PlayerId' : 0,
        'Price' : 0,
        'PV' : 'null',
        'Seconds' : 0,
        'Type' : 1}],
    'IsNeedUpdatePromoCode' : 'true',
    'Lng' : "ru",
    'NeedUpdateLine' : 'false',
    'partner' : 51,
    'UserId' : user_1x,
    'Vid' : 0
    }
```

headers такие же как и у get-запросов, только меняется адрес, на который отправляется запрос.
Пробовал повторить и с помощью requests и seleniumrequests, ничего не происходит.

```
driver_1x.request('POST', 'https://1xstavka.ru/live', json=json)
```

получилось добавить купон с помощью requests

```
s = requests.Session()
s.get("https://1xstavka.ru")
a = s.post('https://1xstavka.ru/LiveUtil/UpdateCoupon', json=json)
a = a.json()
```

В программе приходит ответ, который присылает сайт, если сам делаешь через браузер.
Есть возможность отправить такой же запрос с помощью seleniumrequests, чтобы на сайте было видно добавление купона?

Comment: На вопрос, как это сделать, ответ - повторить то, что делает браузер. Почему у вас не получается, ответить нельзя, если вы не добавите в вопрос необходимую для этого информацию, а именно: 1. запрос который посылает браузер (можно достать из консоли разработчика) 2. код , которым вы пытались сделать то же. В текущем виде вопрос подлежит закрытию, по причине отсутствия необходимых деталей.

Comment: Извините, добавил все моменты.

Comment: Попробуйте еще раз взглянуть на свой вопрос. Как из него можно увидеть посылаете вы точно такой же запрос (с точностью до всех заголовков) или нет? Ответ, нельзя этого увидеть. Потому и помочь и сказать, что вы делаете не так, мы не можем. Нужен полный запрос (не только тело но и заголовки). Можете просто сравнить запрос (полностью, то что посылается по сети), который браузер посылает и ваша программа и увидите, что они разные, а нужно чтоб были одинаковы, тогда сервер не сможет отличить программу от браузера. Используйте для этого в зависимости от вашей ОС что-то из netcat/fiddler/tcpdump.

Comment: Если я захожу и авторизуюсь на сайт при помощи driver.get, почему не получается через driver.request('POST', url=url, json=json) отправить запрос?

Comment: driver.request('POST', url=url, json=json) присылает ответ 200, значит запрос проходит отлично. Но на сайте все равно ничего не происходит, с чем может быть связано? Запрос повторил в точности как в fiddler-e.